# Gem fails to build on MackbookPro with M2 silicon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, poppler, gio

```
OS: Ventura 13.2.1
M2-Max Silicon
Ruby 3.1.0
Rails 7.0.2
```

I did a clean install on this machine:

```
installed homebrew
user homebrew to install rbenv
used rbenv to install ruby 3.1.0
installed the rails 7.0.2 gem set
used homebrew to install MySQL
```

Nothing was transferred from the old machine, with the exception of my source code files.

I am trying to do a

```
bundle run
```

And at one point, I get:

```
Installing gio2 3.5.1 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
..........
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [gio2.bundle] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

An error occurred while installing gio2 (3.5.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
In Gemfile:
poppler was resolved to 3.5.1, which depends on cairo-gobject


Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: If you've migrated from an x86_64 machine you may need to clear out your old libraries completely. Homebrew, in particular, needs to be pretty much expunged and resinstalled or you'll have lingering Intel libraries.

Comment: I did a clean install and did not import any libraries from the X86 machine. This included installing homebrew from scratch, ruby, rails gems, etc.

Comment: Does `gem install cairo-gobject` work? Is that the root problem here?

Comment: I am not sure what the problem is anymore. I tried gem install poppler and gem install cairo-gojet and both worked fine. But when I add poppler to my Gemfile, it fails with the messages I listed.

Comment: It could be an issue with a particular version that's not up to date. If this gem was patched for ARM, you may need to unpin that version and try again.